# how to correctly measure print size & distance from web?

Tags: printing, calculation, measurement

I'm trying to build a t-shirt printing website and I'm currently stuck on how to correctly measure/calculate the position of the print on x/y axis and the print size itself.

You can get the idea of what I mean by

> 1. visiting [spreadshirt](https://www.spreadshirt.com/create-your-own?productType=210)
> 2. selecting any print
> 3. trying to move / resize the print
> 4. the measurement will be the same regardless of the screen/font size

I'm not sure how exactly the calculation happens but I was thinking that maybe I could get the device *dpi* then convert pixels to inches based on the result. But sadly that won't give correct measurements in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need *dpi* of anything of this sort.

Because you have a box (t-shirt in this case) of fixed and known size and position.

When a user moves an element inside the box you can calculate the element's position and size **relative to the box**.

And all you need to do is something like:

```
scale = box.width_in_inches / box.width_in_pixels
el.x_in_inches      = (el.x_in_pixels - box.x_in_pixels)*scale
el.y_in_inches      = (el.y_in_pixels - box.y_in_pixels)*scale
el.width_in_inches  = (el.width_in_pixels              )*scale
el.height_in_inches = (el.height_in_pixels             )*scale
```

`box.width_in_inches` can change when user selects t-shirt of a different size.
`box.width_in_pixels` will change when user zooms the page.
But all `*_in_pixels` values will change respectively.

---

**Update:**
Answering to your comments:

1. Maybe your're getting wrong measurements in your code because they are wrong from the beginning: the ratio of t-shirt's width and height

   1. in inches: 22 / 30.5 = **0.72...**
   2. in pixels of the picture: 452 / 548 = **0,8248...** (or on the page in my browser: 1428,750 / 1732,190 = 0,8248...)
   3. in pixels with bounds you've set up: (1428,750−160) / (1732,190−100) = **0,777...**

      So I had to fix it somehow. I choose to remove the bounds, so that the 
      logo can move and stretch inside the t-shirt picture freely. And 
      decided that t-shirt width in inches should be 30.5*(452/548) = 
      25,157..., not 22.
2. Then just as a sound check I set logo width to maximum and move it to the top. Now it's time for experiments. The expected results should be reasonably close to
   `{ x:0, y:0, w: 25,157, h: 9.07 }`
3. With this function:

   ```js
   // const shirt_w_in_inches = 30.5*(452/548)
   const shirt_h_in_inches = 30.5

   function get_measurements() {
     const pixels_shirt = shirt.getBoundingClientRect()
     const pixels_logo  = logo .getBoundingClientRect()
     const scale = shirt_h_in_inches / pixels_shirt.height
     const inches = {
       x: (pixels_logo.x - pixels_shirt.x)*scale,
       y: (pixels_logo.y - pixels_shirt.y)*scale,
       w: (pixels_logo.width             )*scale,
       h: (pixels_logo.height            )*scale,
     }

     console.log("pixels_shirt", pixels_shirt)
     console.log("pixels_logo" , pixels_logo)
     console.log("inches"      , inches)

     return inches
   }
   ```

   I find them quite reasonable.

   The worst case I was able to find with an maximum error of around 1% of t-shirt width is when I set a 500% zoom, and refresh the page, and then if I resize my browser to 25% of initial window size (and I couldn't set it less). In this case I get these measurements:
   `{x: 0.153..., y: 0.172..., w: 24.920..., h: 8.948...}`

   But if I add `inches.width` and `inches.x` I will get 25.073 - which gives 0.3% - an average error I've observed.
4. So you can ask: "What about `x` and `y`? They are never 0!".
   I'm sorry to break it to you but it looks like an issue with *Moveable* you're using. If I use this function:

   ```js
   function set_full_size() {
     const pixels_shirt = shirt.getBoundingClientRect()
     const pixels_logo  = shirt.getBoundingClientRect()
     logo.style.left    = shirt.clientLeft  + 'px'
     logo.style.top     = shirt.clientTop   + 'px'
     logo.style.width   = shirt.clientWidth + 'px'
     logo.style.height  = shirt.clientHeight*pixels_logo.height/pixels_logo.clientWidth + 'px'
   }
   ```

   It not only sets zeros for `x` and `y`, but also you'll get a smaller error for width. Probably that's because of controls the *Moveable* puts around logo.

Comment: could u plz add an example ?

Comment: The site you've linked uses SVG, what do you use - I don't know. The data structures and field's names of yours - I don't know. How do you get the size of a t-shirt from a user - I also don't know. And I suppose you know how to get element's dimensions in pixels. So I don't really see what is missing from the code I've already provided. But If you'll update your question with a code example I'll be able to fix it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/muah003/r9kfay7q/21) for the box measurements its `30.5inch H x 22inch W`

Comment: Sorry, right now I'm at That part of the world where I can't connect to jsfiddle :). And my VPN just broke. Can you put the code on github?

Comment: yeah sure, np [gist](https://gist.github.com/ctf0/943ae5d1008bfd75abe8e30245a9ce99)